# Unable to mount disk to directory

Tags: linux

I'm getting this error while mounting disk to directory. Please let me know what should I do ?

```
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mkdir filesystem
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mount /dev/xvdf /filesystem
mount: mount point /filesystem does not exist
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# ls
filesystem  
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mount /dev/xvdf /filesystem
mount: mount point /filesystem does not exist
```

Comment: The directory gets created in the current directory but is referred to as `/filesystem`. Make sure the directory is created under root: `mkdir /filesystem`

Comment: This is no question about programming and therefore off topic here. It should be asked on a linux site, there are some here on SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a directory called *filesystem* in the current directory and not under root. Either of the following fixes should work:

A. Make the *filesystem* directory under root

```
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mkdir /filesystem

[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mount /dev/xvdf /filesystem
```

B. Use the *filesystem* directory created under the current directory as mount point

```
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mkdir filesystem
[root@ip-172-31-39-36 ec2-user]# mount /dev/xvdf filesystem
```